# How to get a working Android emulator with NFC in Android Studio under Linux

Tags: android, linux, nfc

I am trying to get an Android emulator working in Android Studio with the NFC enabled, under Linux Mint. 
I have been breaking my head about this. I downloaded the open-nfc but it seems to work only under Windows. And although I found some topics regarding this same question, the solution seems to be incomplete. There seemed to be a Linux version of the open-nfc but I couldn't find the web for this open-nfc anymore.

Thanks in advance and sorry if the topic is repeated or doesn't belong here.

Comment: See https://sourceforge.net/projects/open-nfc/files/Open%20NFC%204.5.2%20%2816234%29/ 

You'll find a Linux version there. But I couldn't get it to work. Do you know how to set it up?